# Expression is always true and redundant catch?

Tags: c#, resharper

I have the following method and Resharper tells me that the `if(drivers != null)` will always be true, but I don't know why and it tells me that the `catch` block is redundant, but can someone explain why?  Here is the code:

```
public List<Driver> GetDrivers(int id)
        {
            if (_context != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    var drivers = _context.Drivers.Where(x=> x.id == id).ToList();


                    //Always true
                    if (drivers != null)
                    {
                        //code
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Heuristically unreachable
                        throw new Exception("No Driver");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return drivers;
        }
```

1. Why is `if(drivers != null)` always true?  Can't drivers be null?  If it is correct, I am assuming there is a default value for drivers that is not null.
2. I am assumming that it is telling the else statement is unreachable because it thinks driver can never be null, but is this the case?
3. It tells me the `catch` is redundant, but besides being null, which
   resharper says it can't, isn't there another exception that can be
   thrown that would cause the `catch` to execute?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using .Where, which returns a collection. If there's no match it will be an empty collection, therefore not null.

I think you want to use .SingleOrDefault instead of .Where.

Comment: So, I guess I could then check for drivers.Count, correct?  Why when I hover over Where, does it say it can throw an ArgumentNullException? Is it talking about the arguments in the Where clause or what Where returns?

Comment: Yes, in this case you can check for drivers.Count. However, I like to be explicit about my intentions so in this case I would do a .Any with returns a Boolean. I think that would be the most efficient.

Comment: What difference does it make if I use SingleOrDefault instead of Where?

Comment: Ok, not too caught up on the efficieny of these things. Thanks for the Any pointer.

Comment: SingleOrDefault will return null or an instance of Driver. Where returns a collection of drivers which may be empty.

Comment: The part that resharper says is Heuristically unreachable, is it saying that only because there is a possibility it can be reached if I change the query from Where to SingleOrDefault for example?

Comment: Yes, in the code sample you've given, drivers can never ever be null. If you adjust the query so it can then the resharper message should disappear.

Comment: Is there any benefit to using SingleOrDefault over Where?  or is it a matter of "I except there to only be one instance of this Driver", so it is best to use SingleOrDefault?

Comment: I like to be explicit with my expectations, so I would code that way. So yes => "I except there to only be one instance of this Driver"

Answer (score 5):

Well the catch is redundant indeed, you're not doing anything in it, simply re-throwing the exact same exception:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
   // would make more sense if for example you're writing to log file

   // otherwise this will be thrown anyway (even without the catch)
   throw;
}
```

Also, this never returns null, it could have 0 entries, but it won't be null:

```
_context.Drivers.Where(x=> x.id == id).ToList();
```

Comment: I plan on adding logging to it, so I guess it won't be redundant then.

Comment: Yes, totally, then it makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 2):

The try blockis redundant because you're just throwing the error again and not doing any additional handling. If you remove the `try/catch` the exception will bubble up anyways. You don't need to throw it.

And `.Where` returns a collection. It'll never be null, but it might be empty.

Comment: Ok, so if I add logging for example, it is not redundant anymore?